# What happens when a return statement where method calls itself? Recursion.

Tags: java, recursion

So I made this simple code with some help of a tutorial. Going through it i am not quite sure what happens at `return faktor(tall-1)*tall`.

in the return statement the method calls itself and returns a value. What happens first? Does it call itself first, or does it first return the values, or do they both happen at the same time?

When it returns the values what happens then?

```
package enkelrekursjon1;

public class Enkelrekursjon1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.print(faktor(3)); 
    }

    private static int faktor(int tall){
    System.out.print(tall); 
    if (tall != 1){
    return faktor(tall - 1)*tall; 
    }    
    return 1; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have wondered about it myself and the best way to know it is by letting the program find it out, so I modified your code to see what actually happens. Here is the code that I modified (I commented and written it in your native tongue and I think we live in the same country. Er ikke norsk dog. lol.)

```
public class EnkelRekursjon1 {

    private static String funksjonNavn= "";
    private static int resultat=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int tall = 3; 
       System.out.print(tall+"! = "+faktor(3)); // resultat printes etter rekursjon 
    }

    private static int faktor(int tall){
    funksjonNavn="Faktor("+tall+")"; 
    System.out.println(tall);
    //finn hvilken funksjon vi er. 
    System.out.println("Funksjonen kaller "+ funksjonNavn);
    if (tall != 1){
        resultat= faktor(tall - 1)*tall; 
        System.out.println("Reusltatet er "+ resultat);
        return resultat; 
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    //finn resultat for hver "rekursjon"
    System.out.println("Reusltatet er "+ (resultat+1));
    //blir 1* 0 her tror jeg, så funksjonen returnerer 1 istedenfor 0   
        return 1; 
    }

}
```

and here is the result:

[image]

If you want to evaluate it manually, it will look like this .

```
faktor(5) = faktor(4)*5
```

we'll get the value of faktor(4), and it's like this:

```
faktor(4) = faktor(3)*4
```

we'll do the same to the rest of the "faktor(int tall)" until the condition is false.

```
faktor(3) = faktor(2)*3 
faktor(2) = faktor(1)*2
```

**faktor(1) will return 1 since tall is equal to 1** (hence, the condition is false). substituting faktor(1) with 1,

we get:

```
faktor(2) = 1*2 =2
```

substitute faktor(2) with 2, we get

```
faktor(3)= 2 * 3 = 6
```

substituting faktor(3) with 6, we get

```
faktor(4)= 6*4 = 24
```

finally, we get:

```
faktor(5) = 24*5 = 120
```

I hope it's clear enough this time

I hope I have answered your question. Please don't hesitate to ask if you have further questions. Ha ein fin dag :)

Comment: Ja, vi bor begge i norge, så kult!  I think I will try to watch a youtube video to see what happens. Hopefully someone can draw it out for me.

Comment: øhmm.. I'm not sure, but is the screenshot of result quite unclear? 

btw, jeg har lagt deg til på fb. håper vi kan bli venner. takk :)

Comment: The screenshot was a little bit unclear, but wasn't a big problem because I could just print it out myself with your code, but apparently there are stacks involved in and all that, there is some magic behind the scenes, so I am not sure a written explanation can help. sure I can add you on facebook

Answer (score 8):

It works the same way a return statement returning a value always works:

- The expression is evaluated (in this case `faktor(tall - 1) * tall`)
- The value is returned to the caller

It can't possibly return *before* evaluating the expression, because there'd be no value to return.

So in your case, if you have call `faktor(5)` you'll end up with a call stack of:

```
faktor(5)
   -> calls faktor(4)
         -> calls faktor(3)
               -> calls faktor(2)
                     -> calls faktor(1)
                           -> returns 1
                     -> returns 1 * 2 (i.e. 2)
               -> returns 2 * 3 (i.e. 6)
         -> returns 6 * 4 (i.e. 24)
   -> returns 24 * 5 (i.e. 120)
```

Comment: Does it have to loop through every faktor(tall-1)*tall before it will be returned? I don't get it yet.

Comment: @DavidLund: What do you mean by "before it will be called"? Before *what* will be called? Your comment is very unclear... Have you tried debugging through your code step by step, or adding logging? Those are probably the simplest ways of understanding what's going on.

Comment: I meant returned I am sorry. I edited. Yes, i have tried going through my code step by step but there is something I am misunderstanding that doesn't make it right.

Comment: @DavidLund: Well it's not clear from your comments what you don't understand or what you mean by "that doesn't make it right" unfortunately :(

Comment: If you put in 5, okey, it prints out 5 which is ok, and then it returns 20? (5-1*5) to where? and calls itself again with the number 4 again and prints out 4.

Comment: @DavidLund: No, faktor(5) returns 120. I suggest you change `System.out.print` calls to `System.out.println` so you don't get all the numbers on the same line.

Comment: Okey, so I need to ask my first question again. You enter 5, it prints out 5. t It goes to the return statement return faktor(tall - 1)*tall; and it says: Hey I need to figure out what faktor(tall-1) is so it loops through the method again?

Comment: @DavidLund: I wouldn't say it "loops through" because a loop is a different construct - but it calls the method again, yes. Note that at this point you've got two method calls on the stack, each with their own independent `tall` parameter.

Comment: I finally understood it. it only returns the value one time, but goes through call for the method on each stack until it hits 1. it remembers each method and each varible on each stack.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive structure. It uses the condition

```
if(tall != 1)
```

as the base case. So this method will go through and do some work, check if tall is equal to one, if not it will go through and operate on the data again. So on and so forth until the base case is satisfied (tall==1)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

First, if the condition is true, the method calls itself. The method will only return when tall reaches 1.